# Proving $\pi$ irrational: help with Lambert's proof. "Circularity"?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

This expression is irrational. 
$$\tan(x)=\frac{x}{1-\frac{x^2}{3-\frac{x^2}{5-...}}}$$
But then he used the fact that $\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}=1$, so $\frac{\pi}4$  is irrational. But how can we use tangent function here if we are proving the irrationality of $\pi$. 
And is there any simpler proof also? (Using elementary functions and operations)

Comment: Why should we not be allowed to use the tangent function?

Comment: Because, tangent function is taking $\pi$ as the input, and how can we input it when we are not sure if it is irrational or rational, we are proving it.

Comment: We use numbers all the time without knowing whether they are rational or irrational.

Comment: For other proofs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational

Comment: @RobertIsrael But we are especially proving the irrationality of $\pi$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is false. Probably the correct version is that your continued fraction is irrational **if** $x$ is rational. Therefore, since we know that $\tan(\frac{π}{4})$ is rational, $\frac{π}{4}$ **cannot** be rational.

Comment: How do we know that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$ is rational, if we don't know if $\pi/4$ is rational.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Read my argument carefully. **If** $\frac{π}{4}$ is rational, what do you know about $\tan(\frac{π}{4})$?

Comment: Ohh, gotcha! Uh..Wait. But then how do we know that $\tan(\frac{\pi}4)=1$? Sorry, I know I am skeptical!

Comment: How do we know that. Ain;t it "circular"?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Ah that's a good question. It is then a completely different question. The definition of $π$ is what you want. If it is defined as the perimeter of a circle of diameter $1$, or area of circle of radius $1$, then you need a lot of work to prove things like $\sin(π) = 0$. But some authors define $π$ as the first positive root of $\cos$, in which case it would take a lot of work to prove the geometric facts about $π$. So take your pick of definition but know that you get roughly the same amount of work to prove everything.

Comment: Hmm. What would be a good start?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Sorry I missed your last comment. I recommend starting with the differential equation $f' = f$ with $f(0) = 1$ and approximating $f$ around $0$ using polynomials. Continue to the infinite series and use squeeze theorem to prove that it converges and then that its derivative is itself. If done right the proof is the same even if $f$ is a function on complex numbers. Now using the differential equation it is easy to prove all the properties of the exponential. Similarly $f'' = f$ and suitable initial conditions define $\cos,\sin$ and $\exp(ix) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$. [continued]

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Using this and the properties of the exponential you can find that $\exp(ix)$ goes round the unit circle.. and continuity implies that there is a period, which we define half of it to be $π$, which would be $2\sin^{-1}(1)$. Now if we also define arc-length it is easy to prove that the semi-circle has arc-length $π$. Similarly for area. The reason this is better than starting with geometry is that geometric definitions only give rise to the involved functions with domain restricted to the reals, which do not extend naturally to the complex numbers.