# Lambert's related proof of the irrationality of $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

It appears in the book of number theory, and I don't understand the proof actually. There is a corollary (from a theorem) that states that

**Corollary** If $x\in\mathbb{Q}, x\not = \dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\exists k\in\mathbb Z$. Then $\tan x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

The proof that $\pi$ is irrational (in the book) is that they assumed $\pi\in\mathbb Q$ and so is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ but $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=1\in\mathbb{Q}$, which contradicts that $\tan (\pi/4)\not\in\mathbb Q$ from the corollary. I don't understand why we didn't use $\pi$ itself instead of $\pi/4$ as it satisfies the condition and yields the contradiction as well. I wonder that I miss some points in the case, so that the book has to use $\pi/4$?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{4}\not\in\mathbb Q$, hence $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$ is not a counterexample to the claim. But they missed $\tan(0)=0$. Moreover , it should be $k\in\mathbb Z$ to cover also the negative $x$.

Comment: Yes, it's typo for $k$, but I don't want to find the counter example. I just type in the proof from the book to be a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lambert's proof see for example [here](http://www.pi314.net/eng/lambert.php), where he used $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$. As noted in this text, we could also have used $\tan(\pi)=0$ for the proof, but Lambert didn't. For a detailed account of this proof see also this post:

[Lambert's Original Proof that $\pi$ is irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895611/lamberts-original-proof-that-pi-is-irrational)

Remark: It is funny, how many "difficulties" arise with this proof by Lambert, see for example

[Proving $\pi$ irrational: help with Lambert's proof. "Circularity"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397213/proving-pi-irrational-help-with-lamberts-proof-circularity)